# EPMP on pic24fj128da210

Tags: pic

Does anyone have any experience in using the Enhanced Parallel Master Port on the PIC24 family?

I am trying to use the example on page 42 of the [EPMP manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39730B.pdf) - the "Read Example".

My problem is that the example doesn't even begin to even think about the vaguest possibility of working.  The very first bit:

```
#define EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_SIZE  0x20000L
#define CS_START_ADDRESS        0x200000L

// define an array in EPMP EDS space to access the external resource
__eds__ char pmp_data[EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_SIZE]
    __attribute__((space(eds), address(CS_START_ADDRESS), noload));
```

will not compile.  It complains:

```
error: size of array ‘pmp_data’ is too large
```

Now, the EPMP on this chip has 23 address lines.  That's a massive 8MB of address space - coupled with 2 CS lines, so a total possible of 16MB.  This is only 256KB I am using (the example in the manual is for 2 x 128KB memory chips, which is as it happens just what I have here).

So what's the game here?  I have had a poke around in the linker scripts, but nowhere in any of the chips' scripts can I see any mention of the EDS space.  I am, quite frankly, lost in those gld files, and last time I tried tinkering with one it broke it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get to answer this one myself.

Buried deep inside some example code lost somewhere in the MCP website I find this:

> Notes:
>
> 1. Using arrays larger than 32K must be compiled with: -mlarge-arrays 
>        This file is set to compile with this setting. Please refer to the C30 
>        User's Manual for details on -mlarge-arrays (DS51284)
>
>    ...

Now, you'd have thought that they'd have maybe mentioned that in the EPMP manual, now wouldn't you?